# Base64 Decoder not outputting UTF-8

Tags: java, base64, apache-commons

I have my Base64 decoder:

```
public class Decoder {
    public static void Decode() throws IOException{
        String s = "";
        String output = "";
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.txt"));

            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                s += sc.nextLine();
                System.out.println(s);
            }
            sc.close();
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decodeBase64(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.txt")));
        Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.png"), "UTF8"));
        for(int i =0; i < bytes.length; i++){
            output+=bytes[i];
            out.write(bytes[i]);
            System.out.println((char)bytes[i]);
        }
      out.close();
      System.out.println("Your File has been saved at C:\\Users\\Dragon\\Desktop\\Binary\\Base64.png");
    }
}
```

And when I input

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAsklEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwUADPOYG/5ExujxeA0Aa0AG6ITgNgGle9O05HF/89fm/we29KIZgNQCmGaQBphkEvN5eBGOiDYBpBBkEwyADkF2BYQC65p4vj1CwwtRGFFfgNQBkIy4DYK7AaQBIs87ZjVgNkK7OBmO8BsACDKQBGYMMBWEQG6sBsEAEaQbZAtMAwzAxnGEAMwDkR1wGwGwnmJCQnYzudKKTMjaMNylTnBvJxQAdEGHNXhVMiwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

into it I get:

```
ﾉPNG


IHDR         ￳a   tEXtAuthor minecraftinfo.com￟f'K   ﾲIDAT8ￋc￸?%￁@<￦ﾑ1ﾺ<^@￐ﾺ!8
ﾀi^￴￭9_￼￵￹﾿￁￭ﾽ(ﾆ`5 ﾦﾤﾦﾼ￞^cﾢ
ﾀiￃ ﾐ]ﾁa ﾺ￦ﾞ/ﾏPﾰￂￔFW￠5 d#.`ﾮ￀i Hﾳￎ￙ﾍX
ﾐﾮￎcﾼ￀ﾤﾃaﾫﾰ@i￙ￓ ￃ01ﾜa 3 ￤G\￀l'ﾘﾐﾐﾝﾌ￮tﾢﾓ26ﾌ7)Sﾜ￉ￅ aￍ^Lﾋ    IENDﾮB`ﾂ
```

And the expected output is:

```
‰PNG


IHDR         óÿa   tEXtAuthor minecraftinfo.comßf'K   ²IDAT8Ëcøÿÿ?%Á@<æÿ‘1º<^@Ðº!8
€i^ôí9_üõù¿Áí½(†`5 ¦¤¦¼Þ^c¢
€iÃ ]a ºæž/P°ÂÔFWà5 d#.`®Ài H³ÎÙX
®Îc¼À¤ƒa«°@iÙÓ Ã01œa 3 äG\Àl'˜Œît¢“26Œ7)SœÉÅ aÍ^L‹    IEND®B`‚
```

And I know my encoder is working correctly because when I put my

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAYAAAAf8/9hAAAAGHRFWHRBdXRob3IAbWluZWNyYWZ0aW5mby5jb23fZidLAAAAsklEQVQ4y2P4//8/AyUYwUADPOYG/5ExujxeA0Aa0AG6ITgNgGle9O05HF/89fm/we29KIZgNQCmGaQBphkEvN5eBGOiDYBpBBkEwyADkF2BYQC65p4vj1CwwtRGFFfgNQBkIy4DYK7AaQBIs87ZjVgNkK7OBmO8BsACDKQBGYMMBWEQG6sBsEAEaQbZAtMAwzAxnGEAMwDkR1wGwGwnmJCQnYzudKKTMjaMNylTnBvJxQAdEGHNXhVMiwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==
```

into this website:
http://www.base64decode.org/ I get the expected output. What's wrong with my decoder?

Comment: Which `Base64` class are you using?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm using rg.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Hello?